# android can't even run "Hello World"

Tags: android, eclipse

I just want to run "Hello World" in android, but my eclipse console show:

```
Failed to install hello.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
(null)
Launch canceled!
```

My eclipse logcat show:

```
executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
* and many more
```

I have read many tutorial on website and follow the steps:

1. install jdk1.7.0_51 (64-bit)
2. install android SDK 22.6.2 from (http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22.6.2-windows.exe)
3. use sdk manager to download API level 19
4. download eclipse kepler 4.3.2 (64-bit)
5. install ADT plug-in from this url(https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)
6. make a AVD

I also have download the adt-bundle which said With a single download, the ADT Bundle includes everything you need to begin developing apps. But not work too for both 32bit and 64bit.

Is this because of version of sdk,jdk,adt-plugin, and other not match or what?
Can give me a set of version of sdk, jdk, adt-plugin... that is work, and the link to download it?

Comment: Can you try to delete the emulator and create a new one? Or uninstall the sdk and reinstall. I got only the sdk and the emulator startup is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JDK v1.6.45 instead. You can find v1.6.45 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u45-oth-JPR).

JDK v7 is not supported by Android yet.

Also, if you use Android SDK v22.6.2, you MUST also use ADT v22.6.2.

Comment: Is your IDE using JDK v6 or v7? You MUST point Eclipse at JDK v6.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use Eclipse+ADT Bundle (No need to setup add-ons and other sdk stuff)

Go here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

and click on `Download the SDK` button

Comment: i have installed JDK v1.6.45 and use Eclipse+ADT Bundle (No need to setup add-ons and other sdk stuff), but still have error.

Comment: Try using API Level 18 or lower on emulator.